# Socket io won't connect on phonegap

Tags: node.js, socket.io, phonegap

Gud day gurus please am having this issue with socket io it connects when the app is not sign but won't connect when app is sign every works fine ajax works don't know wat is the issue please help tnx

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question, so it fulfils the perks of a good question.

Comment: Any solution to this issue??

Answer (score 0):

On your command line make sure you navigate to where your Socket.IO folder is located before you start the app and start the server.